# Проблема линейной регрессии

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, линейная-алгебра, регрессия

кого заинтересовал мой заголовок, сейчас я попробую как можно подробнее и интереснее описать проблему с которой я столкнулся в процессе изучения основ машинного обучения. Решая учебную задачу с kaggle, я захотел сравнить различные модели в решении одной и той же задачи, чтобы сравнить их эффективность в различных условиях, но использовать реализацию из *sklearn* не интересно, поэтому я решил написать собственные аналоги моделей, и решено было начать с **линейной регрессии**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс "model" должен используя функцию *Lineal_Regression(x, y)*, принимающую на вход:

x - numpy массив из массивов записей нашего датасета

y - numpy массив из результатов, которые мы хотим предсказывать для тестовых данных

```
import numpy as np
class model():

    def Lineal_Regression(self, x, y):...

    def factorial(self, n):...

    def RepComb(self, m, n):...

    def RSS(self, x, y):...
```

Начнём с вспомогательных функций, как не трудно догадаться *factorial(n)* ищет факториал, а *RepComb(m, n)* перестановки с повторениями.

Как и в *LinearRegression()* из *sklearn*, было решено взять за функцию ошибки RSS т.е. так называемые наименьшие квадраты. Мы создаём функцию, которая считает сумму квадратов отклонений и пытаемся её минимизировать и тем самым найти заветные коэффициенты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моей реализация функция принимает на вход вышеописанные x и y и выдаёт массив коэффициентов вида: [ω0^2, ω1^2, ..., ωn^2, ω0*ω1, ω0*ω2, ..., ω0ωn, ω1ω2, ..., ω1*ωn, ..., ω(n-1)ωn, ω0, ω1, ..., ωn, a]

Где ω0^2 - коэффициент стоящий перед β0^2, ω1 - коэффициент перед β1 и так далее. А самый последний элемент это константное значение функции RSS. Проще говоря он раскрывает скобки и находит коэффициенты при неизвестных.

Например для x = [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6nrO.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luaqi.png)], y = [2, 3]

SSR = (1 * ω1 + ω0)^2 + (2 * ω1 + ω0)^2

На что моя функция выдаст:

```
[  2.   5.   6. -10. -16.  13.]
```

Что означает SSR = 2ω0^2 + 5ω1^2 + 6ω0ω1 - 10ω0 - 16ω1 + 13

Вот её полная реализация:

```
    def RSS(self, x, y):
        x = np.insert(x, 0, [1] * x.shape[0], axis=1)
        res = np.array([0.0] * int(self.RepComb(2, x.shape[1]) + x.shape[1] + 1))

        for k in range(x.shape[0]):
            res[-1] += y[k]**2

            for i in range(x.shape[1]):
                res[i] += x[k][i]**2

            i = x.shape[1]
            for j in range(x.shape[1] - 1):
                for l in range(j + 1, x.shape[1]):
                    res[i] += 2 * x[k][j] * x[k][l]
                    i += 1

            for j in range(x.shape[1]):
                res[i] += -2 * x[k][j] * y[k]
                i += 1

        return res
```

И теперь мы переходим к самому главному, к реализации самой *Lineal_Regression(x, y)* перед которой ставится задача отыскать ω0, ..., ωn такие, что функция RSS является минимальной. Первая моя идея заключалась в том, чтобы найти частные производные функции и прировнять их к нулю, мы получаем (n + 1) переменную и (n + 1) неизвестную, находим стационарную точку, которая исходя из здравого смысла будет минимальной, так как устремляя ω0, ..., ωn в разные стороны на бесконечность, значение RSS будет только увеличиваться.

Зная коэффициенты, задача показалась мне не сложной, её графическое значение я попытался изобразить от руки, несмотря на то, что не одарён художественными навыками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как матрица производных будет симметричной, достаточно найти только верхний диагональный вид, после чего прибавить транспонированную и вычесть одну диагональку.

Так же необходимо найти вектор решений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего решить обычную СЛАУ

И случилось чудо, моя линейная регрессия начала выдавать результаты идентичные результатам *LinealRegression()* из пакета *sklearn*, например:

```
x = np.array([[1.7], [1.62], [1.7], [1.85], [1.85], [1.63], [1.5]])
y = np.array([63, 56, 54, 75, 80, 59, 49])

model1 = model()
res1 = model1.Lineal_Regression(x, y)

m1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
m1.fit(x, y)

print(res1)
print(m1.coef_)
```

Программа выдаёт:

```
[-78.06313282  82.90649196]
[82.90649196]
```

Так же хорошо работает и для многомерного случая:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 4, 6, 5], [2, 3, 3, 4, 5], [4, 2, 5, 4, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 4, 4, 5, 2], [6, 8, 1, 6, 5]])
y = np.array([2, 4, 2.5, 0, 3, 2])

model1 = model()
res1 = model1.Lineal_Regression(x, y)

m1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
m1.fit(x, y)

print(res1)
print(m1.coef_)
```

Вывод:

```
[ 1.19371180e-14 -5.62072893e-01  1.02961276e+00  1.12243736e+00
 -1.32744875e+00  7.95558087e-01]
[-0.56207289  1.02961276  1.12243736 -1.32744875  0.79555809]
```

Но самое больное началось, когда я начал применять модель в реальных боевых условиях, при большом количестве записей она начинает ломаться даже в случае одной переменной, вот пример для [датасета](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("C://Users/79178/Desktop/House Prices/train.csv")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df["LotArea"], df["SalePrice"])

x = np.array([[i] for i in df["LotArea"]])
y = np.array([i for i in df["SalePrice"]])


model3 = model()
res3 = model3.Lineal_Regression(x, y)
ax.plot([0, 200000], [0 * res3[1] + res3[0], 500 * res3[1] + res3[0]])

m3 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
m3.fit(x, y)
r3 = m3.coef_
ax.plot([0, 200000], [0 * r3[0], 500 * res3[1]])

print(res3)
print(r3)
```

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[-4.28049172e+07  4.08733870e+03]
[2.09997195]
```

И выходит предупреждение:

```
C:\Users\79178\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14316\861510427.py:50: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  res[i] += -2 * x[k][j] * y[k]
```

По графику видно, что произошла ошибка как по переменной ω1 так и по ω0. Мной было замечено, что повышая количество записей, всё работает хорошо до какого-то момента, в моём случае до 54ой записи всё совпадает с sklearn решением и на графике выглядит адекватно, но потом, что-то идёт не по плану и решение ломается:

Вот полный код реализации

```
class model():

    def Lineal_Regression(self, x, y):
        if x.shape[0] == y.shape[0]:
            coefs_of_Rss = self.RSS(x, y)
            DifMatrix = np.zeros((x.shape[1] + 1, x.shape[1] + 1))
            vector_sol = -1 * coefs_of_Rss[(x.shape[1]+2) * (x.shape[1] + 1) // 2: (x.shape[1]+2) * (x.shape[1] + 1) // 2 + x.shape[1] + 1]
            sdvig = 0
            for i in range(x.shape[1] + 1):
                for j in range(i, x.shape[1] + 1):
                    if i == j:
                        DifMatrix[i][j] = 2 * coefs_of_Rss[i]
                    else:
                        DifMatrix[i][j] = coefs_of_Rss[x.shape[1] + j + i * x.shape[1] - sdvig]
                sdvig += i + 1

            DifMatrix = DifMatrix + DifMatrix.transpose() - (np.eye(x.shape[1] + 1) * DifMatrix)

            return (np.linalg.solve(DifMatrix, vector_sol))




    def factorial(self, n):
        if n <= 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return self.factorial(n - 1) * n

    def RepComb(self, m, n):
        return self.factorial(m + n - 1) / (self.factorial(m) * self.factorial(n - 1))

    def RSS(self, x, y):
        x = np.insert(x, 0, [1] * x.shape[0], axis=1)
        res = np.array([0.0] * int(self.RepComb(2, x.shape[1]) + x.shape[1] + 1), dtype=np.float64)

        for k in range(x.shape[0]):
            res[-1] += y[k]**2

            for i in range(x.shape[1]):
                res[i] += x[k][i]**2

            i = x.shape[1]
            for j in range(x.shape[1] - 1):
                for l in range(j + 1, x.shape[1]):
                    res[i] += 2 * x[k][j] * x[k][l]
                    i += 1

            for j in range(x.shape[1]):
                res[i] += -2 * x[k][j] * y[k]
                i += 1

        return res
```

Но на этом я не отчаялся и погуглив понял, что можно реализовать данное решение при помощи итерационного метода градиентного спуска, реализация которого совпадает с первой до нахождения коэффициентов матрицы частных производных, отличается только часть функции *Lineal_Regression(x,y)*

```
    def Lineal_Regression(self, x, y):
        if x.shape[0] == y.shape[0]:
            coefs_of_Rss = self.RSS(x, y)
            DifMatrix = np.zeros((x.shape[1] + 1, x.shape[1] + 1))
            vector_sol = np.array([coefs_of_Rss[(x.shape[1]+2) * (x.shape[1] + 1) // 2: (x.shape[1]+2) * (x.shape[1] + 1) // 2 + x.shape[1] + 1]])
            v = np.zeros((x.shape[1] + 1, 1))
            vector_sol = vector_sol.T


            sdvig = 0
            for i in range(x.shape[1] + 1):
                for j in range(i, x.shape[1] + 1):
                    if i == j:
                        DifMatrix[i][j] = 2 * coefs_of_Rss[i]
                    else:
                        DifMatrix[i][j] = coefs_of_Rss[x.shape[1] + j + i * x.shape[1] - sdvig]
                sdvig += i + 1

            DifMatrix = DifMatrix + DifMatrix.transpose() - (np.eye(x.shape[1] + 1) * DifMatrix)

            for _ in range(10000):
                v = v - 0.001*((np.dot(DifMatrix, v)) + vector_sol)

            return v
```

Шаг в 0.001 и количество итераций 10000 были взяты из головы, я сначала хотел убедиться в эффективности метода, а потом его оптимизировать, но как и в прошлом случае, на маленьком наборе данных всё работает хорошо с заданной точностью, но при увеличении этих самых данных, происходит ошибка: v уходит на бесконечность по всем координатам, чего я уже никак не могу понять, даже если шаг подобран неудачно, v всё равно должен "прыгать" вокруг правильного решения, но никак не уходить на бесконечность вот пример для того же датасета:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("C://Users/79178/Desktop/House Prices/train.csv")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df["LotArea"], df["SalePrice"])

x = np.array([[i] for i in df["LotArea"]], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([i for i in df["SalePrice"]], dtype=np.float64)


model3 = model()
res3 = model3.Lineal_Regression(x, y)
ax.plot([0, 200000], [0 * res3[1] + res3[0], 500 * res3[1] + res3[0]])

m3 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
m3.fit(x, y)
r3 = m3.coef_
ax.plot([0, 200000], [0 * r3[0], 500 * res3[1]])

print(res3)
print(r3)
```

Вывод:

```
[[nan]
 [nan]]
[2.09997195]
```

Предупреждение:

```
C:\Users\79178\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14316\78557657.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  v = v - 0.001*((np.dot(DifMatrix, v)) + vector_sol)
c:\users\79178\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py:65: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  ary = asanyarray(ary)
```

Если вы дочитали до этого момента, то мне было бы очень интересно услышать ваши предположения, с чем могут быть связанны мои ошибки, а так же, у меня есть глупый вопрос, на который я пока не нашёл ответ: В чём преимущество использования метода градиентного спуска перед обычным решением СЛАУ в данной задаче? Ведь реализация МГС встречалась чаще в процессе гуглёшки.

Comment: Градиентный спуск нужен чтобы не решать уравнения. Не всегда функция такая хорошая, что можно просто решить линейное уравнение, поэтому и нужен градиентный спуск. А ещё лучше - стохастический градиентный спуск, за счёт стохастичности он лучше обходит локальные минимумы.

Comment: Вставлю свои пять копеек. Можно же найти коэффициенты при параметрах с помощью матричных операций: Составляется матрица А размерностью n*k, где n - число наблюдений, k - индекс последнего коэффициента с учётом того, что свободный член имеет нулевой индекс. Затем решается что-то типа такого

` np.linalg.inv(A.transpose() @ A) @ A.transpose() @ df.Y`

На выходе получим вектор коэффициентов. Как то так))

Answer (score 1):

Перечитывая вопрос, я понял как решить проблему в методе решения обычной СЛАУ, достаточно было всего лишь указать 64-битный тип, dtype=numpy.float64

```
x = np.array([[i] for i in df["LotArea"]], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([i for i in df["SalePrice"]], dtype=np.float64)
```

И проблема решилась :) Но в методе решения через градиентный спуск, всё ещё осталась

Comment: xD это метод утки

Comment: @Senior Pomidor, ахах, забавно, но в процессе написания вопроса, на моём столе действительно была резиновая утка))

Comment: А ведь есть ещё и `np.float128` )